# Alfresco Development . Working with All in one Archetype

Tags: alfresco

I have created a multi module project in Alfresco using All-in-one Archetype of the Maven Alfresco SDK. I have selected 1.1.1 archetype version. The project directory was build successfully. But in that directory I couldnt find the wcmqs(Alfresco Web Quick Start) directory which is used to build websites. Can anyone help me hw to get this wcmqs, as I need to work with wcmqs for creating new pages and templetes in wcmqs?

Comment: I do not think wcmqs is included in that archtype.

Answer (score 0):

The wcmqs module did used to be in the Maven Alfresco SDK but it never worked very well and caused other problems. It is however unnecessary to use the Maven Alfresco SDK if you wish to get started.

To get started with Alfresco Web Quick Start you just need to download and install the files. You can get the files from Sourceforge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/alfresco/files/Alfresco%204.2.f%20Community/

Installation should be straightforward. You need to install the AMPs on your Alfresco instance and deploy the WARs to a servlet container (like your Tomcat).

If you want to customise Web Quick Start, such as changing the model, that is a different matter. There is a short example here that you can go through to give you an idea of what you need to do:
http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2011/01/06/1254